# angular2 help and clarification

Tags: angular

I'm in the process of reading Beginning Angular2 with TypeScript by Greg Lim.

I'm up to chapter 4 and up until now I was doing well, however I just seem to be a bit lost at the min. In app.module I have the following declarations

```
    AppComponent,
    ProductsComponents,
    RatingComponent,
    ProductComponent
```

and in app.components I have

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <products></products>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    title: string = 'app works!!!';
}
```

and in my products.components I have

```
import { ProductService } from './product.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'products',
    template: `<h2>Products</h2>
         <div *ngFor="let product of products">
          <product [data]="product"></product>
          </div>`,
    providers: [ProductService]
})

export class ProductsComponents {
    products; 
    constructor(productService: ProductService) {
    this.products = productService.getProducts();
    }
}
```

In rating.component I have

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: "rating",
    templateUrl: 'rating.component.html',
    styles: [`
        .glyphicon-star { color:orange; }
        `]
})

export class RatingComponent {
    @Input('rating-value') rating = 0;
    @Input() numOfReviews = 0;
    onClick(ratingValue) {
    this.rating = ratingValue;
    }
}
```

In product.component I have

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'product',
    template: `<div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="{{data.imageUrl}}" alt="...">
            </a>
          </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading">{{data.productName}}</h4>
          {{data.releasedDate}}
          <rating
            [rating-value]="data.rating"
            [numOfReviews]="data.numOfReviews">
          </rating>
          <br />
          {{data.description}}
        </div>
          </div>
      `,
    styles: [`
      .media {
      margin-bottom:20px;
      }
    `]
})

export class ProductComponent {
    @Input() data;
}
```

and lastly in product.service I have

```
export class ProductService {
    getProducts() {
    return [
        {
        imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=1",
        productName: "Product 1",
        releasedDate: "May 31, 2016",
        description: "Product description for product 1",
        rating: 2,
        numOfReviews: 5
        },
        {
        imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=2",
        productName: "Product 2",
        releasedDate: "May 31, 2016",
        description: "Product description for product 2",
        rating: 4,
        numOfReviews: 6
        },
        {
        imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=3",
        productName: "Product 3",
        releasedDate: "May 31, 2016",
        description: "Product description for product 3",
        rating: 1,
        numOfReviews: 5
        },
        {
        imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=4",
        productName: "Product 4",
        releasedDate: "May 31, 2016",
        description: "Product description for product 4",
        rating: 5,
        numOfReviews: 1
        }
    ];
    }
}
```

All of which is working fine.

I understand that in products.components is is populating the array that it then passes into the ngFor, but I can't work out how rating.component and product.component are pulled into that for loop.

Can someone explain?

Thanks

Comment: They all use each other inside the templates, what is not clear in this hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is what ngFor does:

```
<h2>Products</h2>
     <div *ngFor="let product of products">
      <product [data]="product"></product>
      </div>
```

gets rendered into:

```
<h2>Products</h2>
     <div>
      <product [data]="product1"></product>
      </div>


     <div>
      <product [data]="product2"></product>
      </div>

      <div>
      <product [data]="product3"></product>
      </div>
...
```

then your each product component contains rating component and feeds it with its particular product (that came from array).

**[UPDATE]**

your products.component has this template:

```
template: `<h2>Products</h2>
         <div *ngFor="let product of products">
          <product [data]="product"></product>
          </div>`,
```

and in your product.component you have set selector:

```
selector: 'product'
```

Notice `<product>` element in your template. That is, at the same time, selector for product.component so angular knows that it should run product.component whenever element `<product>` is used in template.

Comment: I fully understand that, but there doesn't seem to be a link between the product.components file and product.component file apart from in the declaration in the app.module file